# SQL: Why this error when trying to create a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and was trying to create a basic emp table to learn a bit. When I write the query and try to execute it, I keep getting the message "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis". However I feel that I have included a pair of braces for each function. Could anyone please help me to figure out the issue and if possible could correct me if I am wrong??

Below is the sample

```
SQL> create table emp
  2  (emp id number(4),
  3  first name varchar2(25),
  4  last name varchar2(25),
  5  phone number number (10),
  6  department id number (4),
  7  job id number (4),
  8  salary number (6,2),
  9  commission_pct number (4,2),
 10  manager id number (4);
(emp id number (4),
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: Don't just think yourself as entirely new..think yourself as a smart and intelligent guy..you will easily find out such silly errors by looking at the error message..

Answer (score 6):

You have a start parenthesis at line 2;

```
(emp id number(4),
^
```

that is not closed on line 10;

```
manager id number (4);
                     ^missing
```

Also, you can't have spaces in your column names without quoting them. I'd recommend replacing spaces with `_` not to have to quote them everywhere.

```
SQL> create table emp
  2  (emp_id number(4),
  3  first_name varchar2(25),
  4  last_name varchar2(25),
  5  phone_number number (10),
  6  department_id number (4),
  7  job_id number (4),
  8  salary number (6,2),
  9  commission_pct number (4,2),
 10  manager_id number (4));
```

[SQLfiddle test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d58e2/1).

Answer (score 2):

your column has spaces on it, if you want to leave the spaces on your table, wrap it with double quotes `"`

```
create table emp
(
   "emp id" number(4), 
   "first name" varchar2(25),
   .....
);
```

but the best way is to create column names without adding space on it.

```
create table emp
(
   empID number(4), 
   firstName varchar2(25),
   .....
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found 3 mistakes in here.

1. in SQL you must use `numeric` instead of number.
2. you can't keep spaces in field.
3. you need to close the brace end of the query,

Code:

```
 create table emp
       (emp_id numeric(4),
        first_name varchar(25),
        lastname varchar(25),
        phone_number numeric (10),
        department_id numeric (4),
        job_id numeric (4),
        salary numeric (6,2),
        commission_pct numeric (4,2),
        manager_id numeric (4))
```

here is the [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1aff3)

Comment: `number` is a perfectly valid datatype in Oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name he asked this question based on SQL.

Comment: SQL is the query language used by Oracle. So what's your point?